# Open a new buffer on the right

Tags: org-mode, window-splitting

I just upgraded from Fedora Linux 32 to Fedora 33 and I think this updated emacs as well because I now see some new behaviours.
I have set:
`(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'org-todo-list)`
so that I can press F6 to open the TODO list and it used to open on the right, which is what I want.
Now it opens below.
I did some research and found:
`(setq split-width-threshold 1)`
Which does open the TODO list on the right.
BUT when I middle-click on a TODO item in the list, in order to bring the cursor to my org file, in order to mark a TODO item as DONE, sometimes (this seems like a weird behaviour) emacs will open a new window/frame with the org file to the right of the TODO list.
So now I have:
| org file | todo list | same org file |
side by side.
I have been searching for other ways to fix this, but found nothing.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's always good to write alternatives that you tried that can help for others to find some solutions. Beside that can you look for popwin-mode I guess in that way also you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi  itirazimvar, thanks for taking the time to provide suggestion which made me look into things further and found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found using a higher value, eg
`(setq split-width-threshold 100)`
resolved the issue.